# Realm inverse relationship returns object with nil properties

Tags: ios, objective-c, relationship, realm

I got a class named **Team**, it has a RLMArray property called *players* with **Playe**r class objects.
When i try to access the team by calling (according to [documentation](https://realm.io/docs/objc/latest/#relationships))

```
[self linkingObjectsOfClass:@"Team" forProperty:@"players"];
```

on a player object, i get a single team object ( how it's supposed to be ), but all the properties are ***nil***, even primary key.

Has anyone faced the same issue?

Comment: How're you determining that the properties are nil?

Comment: @bdash printing out to the console(even 1 by 1)/viewing via debugger/accessing them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's expected that instance variables of persisted `RLMObject` instances will be `nil` as the property getters read values directly from the Realm file. The instance variables are only used for objects prior to being saved to the Realm, and remain `nil` after that point.

The [Debugging](https://realm.io/docs/objc/latest/#debugging) section of the Realm documentation touches on this topic and mentions an LLDB script that can be used to show property values of persisted objects when debugging in Xcode. The `-description` method on the model classes, used by `NSLog` when formatting objects using the `%@` format specifier, will also show the property values as expected.